# How to set onclick listener for gridview radio buttons in mainactivity instead custom view

Tags: java, android

I want to set `onclicklistener` for radio buttons in `MainActivity` , Right now I have onclick in custom view.

```
public class ToggleButtonGroupTableLayout  extends TableLayout  implements OnClickListener {

    private static final String TAG = "ToggleButtonGroupTableLayout";
    private RadioButton activeRadioButton;

    /**
     * @param context
     */
    public ToggleButtonGroupTableLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @param context
     * @param attrs
     */
    public ToggleButtonGroupTableLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) v;
        if ( activeRadioButton != null ) {
            activeRadioButton.setChecked(false);
        }
        rb.setChecked(true);
        Toast.makeText(getContext(),rb.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if(rb.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Apartment"))
        {


        }

        //radio_button_data(rb.getText().toString());
        activeRadioButton = rb;
    }

}
```

How can I move onclick listener to MainActivity?

Comment: make listener class using interface and implement this in your MainActivity class

Comment: Can you please provide a sample code, I am new to android programming

Answer (score 0):

You can make the custom view in the same class as the main activity and then you can access it easily or you can pass click listener in adapter and over ride OnClick in main activity and perform required actions:

```
public class OnItemClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
    private int position;
    private OnItemClickCallback onItemClickCallback;

    public OnItemClickListener(int position, OnItemClickCallback onItemClickCallback) {
        this.position = position;
        this.onItemClickCallback = onItemClickCallback;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        onItemClickCallback.onItemClicked(view, position);
    }

    public interface OnItemClickCallback {
        void onItemClicked(View view, int position);
    }
}
```

Add this class and pass its object in adpater

Comment: how to access this interface in MainActivity??

Comment: // Pass object of interface here 
Adapter mAdapter = new Adapter(getActivity(), list onItemClickCallBack);

//  use it like the snippet below:
  private OnItemClickListener.OnItemClickCallback onItemClickCallBack = new OnItemClickListener.OnItemClickCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClicked(View view, int position) {}
};